# Uninstall Software but prevent AfterUninstall

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, uninstallation

In the [AfterUninstall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.afteruninstall(v=vs.110).aspx) Event of my installed program(.net / windows7) is some code which is harmful for my OS.

How can I uninstall this program now without running this code?

If I would install a newer version of the same program would this code still run during the execution?

Or are there any other solution to get rid of this program with corrupt uninstaller?

Answer (score 0):

A solution i found is:
Compile a same version with modified/repaired AfterUninstall code.
Copy the program files to the existing corrupt version and overwrite.
Uninstall the corrupt version without problems.